# How to get the HTTP method of an existing route?

Tags: vert.x

In Vert.x (JavaScript), I create [routes](https://vertx.io/docs/jsdoc/module-vertx-web-js_route-Route.html) that match only specific HTTP methods, like for example

```
var route=router.route("POST","/example");
```

How can I determine afterwards which HTTP method the given route was created for?

Answer (score 2):

(i realize you're asking about JavaScript, but as far as i understand, Java is the "base" language from which all the other languages implementations are generated. so, with that being said...)

if you examine the [source code](https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-web/blob/master/vertx-web/src/main/java/io/vertx/ext/web/impl/RouteImpl.java) for `RouteImpl`, you'll find the following declaration:

```
private final Set<HttpMethod> methods = new HashSet<>();
```

if you go on to examine the usage of this collection throughout the class, you'll find that there is no public interface for accessing it or its contents. (well, other than `toString()`, but this is less than ideal for programmatic consumption).

in answer to your question:

> How can I determine afterwards which HTTP method the given route was
>   created for?

out of the box it doesn't appear possible (outside of `toString()`).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have been looking at the Java source before and found the same thing. I would be fine with parsing the method(s) from the string, but unfortunately `route.toString()` just returns `[object Object]` in the JavaScript environment (Vert.x 3.5.4). Do you coincidentally know a way around this?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to retrieve that from the [HttpServerRequest](https://vertx.io/docs/jsdoc/module-vertx-js_http_server_request-HttpServerRequest.html) object, which is retrieved from the [RoutingContext](https://vertx.io/docs/jsdoc/module-vertx-web-js_routing_context-RoutingContext.html), by calling the `method()` function.